# df not filling in for loop, but works manually, Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I am working through this tutorial in Python 2.7: https://github.com/datascienceinc/workshops/blob/master/food_deserts/06-food-deserts-first-attempt.ipynb

I have hit a wall at this code block,

```
nearest_intersection = []
for i in range(chains.shape[0]):
    row = chains.iloc[i]
    r = rtree.query([row.lon, row.lat])
    rownum = r[1]
    refid = lldf.loc[rownum, 'refid']
    nearest_intersection.append(refid)

# GET DISTANCE TO ALL NODES FROM FIRST GROCERY STORE

ni = nearest_intersection[0]
spaths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(g, source=ni, weight='meters')
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ni, 'dest': spaths.keys(), 'dist': spaths.values()})

last_update = -1
for i in range(1, len(nearest_intersection)):
    u = int(10.0 * i / len(nearest_intersection))
    if u != last_update:
        print str(u*10) + '% complete'
        last_update = u
    ni = nearest_intersection[i]
    spaths = nx.single_source_dijkstra_path_length(g, source=ni, weight='meters')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'start': ni, 'dest': spaths.keys(), 'dist': spaths.values()})
    m = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['dest'])
    xmin = m['dist_x'] <= m['dist_y']
    m['dist'] = 9999
    m.ix[xmin, 'dist'] = m[xmin]['dist_x']
    m.ix[xmin, 'start'] = m[xmin]['start_x']
    m.ix[~xmin, 'dist'] = m[~xmin]['dist_y']
    m.ix[~xmin, 'start'] = m[~xmin]['start_y']
    m.drop('dist_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
    m.drop('dist_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
    m.drop('start_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
    m.drop('start_y', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = m
```

The goal is to determine the furthest distance from any node in the networkx graph to any grocery store in the list. The code runs fine when I pull it out of the for loop and run it manually (i.e. I just individually change the i each loop and overwrite the dataframe), but when it runs in this loop I get back an empty df.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is the first or second for loop that is the issue?

Comment: @Joel Sorry, it's the second for loop. I think it's a computational complexity issue. Because when I boost the size of the network significantly the loop will only work for fewer and fewer iterations.